# npm install fails with error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm following this tutorial [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-CD_5YhJTA) but I'v got stuck at 12:41. I downloaded seed project following link in the video description and issued somman `npm install` as administrator on Windows 7. But I'm getting following error:

```
C:\development\angular2\angular2-seed>npm install

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall C:\development\angular2\angular2-seed
> typings install

(I translated following lines to English)
typings is not name of an command, executable or batch.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ch
okidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.0.14: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"
})
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\A
ppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall: `typings install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 postinstall script 'typings ins
tall'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart p
ackage,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\development\angular2\angular2-seed\npm-debug.log
```

Please advise. Thank you.

EDIT: 
Attached file npm-debug.log: [enter link description here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnVEezaTN_ijbhx0Ay5__kXnBWA)
Attached file package.json: [enter link description here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnVEezaTN_ijbwCyUWJgrCzWQ10)

Comment: Please attached the package.json file.

Comment: seed project uses angular2 version `"2.0.0-beta.7"` which is very old. I would suggest you refer this quick start article - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: @ParveenSachdeva I attached npm-debug.log to my question. Thanks.

Comment: @Sanket Thank you for the link. I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 3):

**Permission Issue**. It probably has to do with the path names in windows.

Check the same in Git Bash or Windows Powershell.

You can set the NODE path like : `set NODE_PATH=source`

Remove the node_modules and run `npm install` again.

Comment: I used Git Bash as administrator, set enviroment variable NODE_PATH, deleted node_modules but the issue persists unfortunately. Thank you.

Comment: Please show your package.json file. Would help debug this easier.

Comment: Attached, please see edit of my question. Thank you.

Comment: You need typings installed globally.
```npm install typings --global```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is in my situation facing this error and have tried all the solutions mentioned here, and another similar question, like:

- you are in the right directory
- you have a package.json file,
- the JSON is valid,
- you have tried to run %temp%
- you have tried " npm install -d --save" etc.

Mine worked by doing "npm install --force"

Note: This was also recommended in the error itself, which I didn't pay attention to earlier.

Even " Yarn install" worked.